# Function for F11 fullscreen using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fullscreen

Is it possible to dispaly a web page fullscreen as if you had pressed f11?  In chrome this gets rid of tool bars and everything.  I'm using jQuery but I haven't been able to find info iff this is even possible.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @cherouvim, thanks for the answer.  I guess that would suck to have a virtual desktop but i think that'd still be a chore to be able to replicate a users desktop.  it's not worth going to flash when i can just put a slight call to action saying fullscreen is f11..

Comment: @cherouvim, push f11 and see.

Comment: @Byron Whitlock: He means programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer on this one is old. It's now possible using `HTML5 API`.

And @cherouvim was right, it can be pretty nasty. http://feross.org/html5-fullscreen-api-attack/

Answer (score 11):

The real full screen behavior (F11) is not possible through javascript.

I also think that browsers should never allow access to such behavior because some really bad things could happen. Imagine malicous sites impersonating the user's desktop or something like that. Nasty.

Answer (score 0):

How about if by pressing a javascript linked button a new window would open in full-screen (or displaying address and scroll bars), and just copy the original's page link?